# Convert MS Access query with subquery to MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union

For my website (PHP / MySql) I need some management information.
During a test I was able to produce a working query in MS Access.

Subquery ‘qryUnion’:

```
SELECT Mailadres, Registrationdate FROM tbl-A 
UNION 
SELECT Mailadres, Registrationdate FROM tbl-B;
```

Main query:

```
SELECT Year([Maildate]) & '-' & Month([Maildate]) AS MonthMailed, Count(tbl-C.Mailadres) AS Prospects, Count(qryUnion.Mailadres) AS Members
FROM tbl-C LEFT JOIN qryUnion ON tbl-C.Mailadres = qryUnion.Mailadres
GROUP BY Year([Maildate]) & '-' & Month([Maildate]);
```

I want to convert this to the MySql database. I tried working with an alias or a temporary table, but I can’t get a running code. Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: Any error messages? First thing, Access uses (optional) `[ .. ]` around table names to escape special characters like spaces in the name. I think MySQL uses backticks for that: `\``. Other thing: `&` for concat is different in MySQL. Maybe `||` works, otherwise use the `CONCAT` function. For the rest, read the error message you get and try to solve it one by one. The basic query syntax is the same, but some things are different.

Comment: In MS Access I get the correct information. I'm still looking for the proper way to handle this in MySql. So, I haven't any errors yet.

Comment: You say *"I can't get a running code"*. I assume you have tried running it, but got some error when you tried, or do I completely misunderstand what you mean by *"convert this [query?] to MySQL"*?

Comment: Maybe you should start by showing the attempts you made in MySQL. After all, that's the part you're trying to get working.

Comment: For example, I tried:
(SELECT ‘Mailadres’,’ Registrationdate’ FROM ‘tbl-A’ Union SELECT ‘Mailadres’, ‘Registrationdate’ FROM ‘tbl-B’) INTO #GOS;
SELECT * FROM #GOS;
Respons: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 0):

Move the union to an inline view as below.

You'll likely have to replace your string additions with a CONCAT() function as well and cast the int to CHAR.  I'm not positive I have the syntax correct but this may be close.

```
SELECT concat(cast(Year(`Maildate`) AS CHAR),'-',CAST(Month(`Maildate`) AS CHAR) AS MonthMailed, 
Count(tbl-C.Mailadres) AS Prospects, Count(qryUnion.Mailadres) AS Members
FROM tbl-C 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT Mailadres, Registrationdate FROM tbl-A 
  UNION 
  SELECT Mailadres, Registrationdate FROM tbl-B) qryUnion
  ON tbl-C.Mailadres = qryUnion.Mailadres
GROUP BY concat(cast(Year(`Maildate`) AS CHAR),'-',CAST(Month(`Maildate`) AS CHAR);
```

Corrected ) in wrong place on Year evaluation and cast to char. of select and group by.

Comment: I tried (after the translation to the correct table and column names in my database). Respons: #1064.    Then I put quotes around these names.
Following the code as tried in my database. Respons: again #1064

Comment: SELECT concat(cast(Year('Maildatum' AS CHAR)),'-',CAST(Month('Maildatum') AS CHAR) AS MonthMailed, 
Count('tblProspects'.'Mailadres') AS Prospects, Count(qryUnion.'Mailadres') AS Members
FROM 'tblProspects' 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT 'Mailadres', 'Registratiedatum' FROM 'tblGastouder' 
  UNION 
  SELECT 'Mailadres', 'Registratiedatum' FROM 'tblUitgeschreven') qryUnion
  ON 'tblProspects'.'Mailadres' = qryUnion.'Mailadres'
GROUP BY concat(cast(Year('Maildatum' AS CHAR)),'-',CAST(Month('Maildatum') AS CHAR);

Comment: NM Doesn't )'s are off in select.